# Instagram hashtags and preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I receive a plain description text for some Instagram posts, and try to highlight a hashtags. I use this code:

```
 $caption = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z_.]+)/', '<a href="/tag/$1">#$1</a>', $caption);
```

The problem is: this doesn't work with non-latin characters, like "ş" or "ö". And the second problem: this doesn't work with hashtags without space between, for example, "#quote#quoteoftheday #myquote" - my regular expression will highlight only "#quote" and "#myquote". May I somehow solve these problems in just single regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `(?<!\S)` part so it can also match when there is a non whitespace char in from of # and add the unicode flag `/u`.

You can shorten `0-9a-zA-Z_` to `\w` so your expression might look like:

```
#([\w.]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/agQzZl/1)

```
$caption = "#quote#öquoteoftheday #şmyquote";
$caption = preg_replace('/#([\w.]+)/u', '<a href="/tag/$1">#$1</a>', $caption);
echo $caption;
```

Result:

```
<a href="/tag/quote">#quote</a><a href="/tag/öquoteoftheday">#öquoteoftheday</a> <a href="/tag/şmyquote">#şmyquote</a>
```